# Mutual dependancies between python file

Tags: python

I am writing a program and I want to keep the CORE of my program separate from the GUI (built with Tkinter). However, having two separate python files I'm experiencing the following problem:

GUI.py

```
def bar():
    if a == 'something':
        foo()   

Button(text="START!", command=bar).grid(row=1, column=1)
```

CORE.py

```
from GUI import *

 def foo():
    <do something>
```

and when I launch my program from CORE.py I get:

```
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

I do not know exactly where or what to look for.

Answer (score 3):

You have `foo()` within `GUI.py`, but it is not defined yet when `from GUI import *` line is called from `CORE.py`, therefore the error.

You can move the `foo` definition into `GUI.py` for this simple case

Typically the GUI depends on the "core" modules, though, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should reference your modules the other way around:

```
# core.py
def foo():
    # Do something
```

And then from the GUI module you reference and call your core module

```
# gui.py
from core import foo

def bar():
    foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

Having distinct layers for the domain (what you call "core") and the UI is a very sane design, but only if the domain knows nothing of the UI - it's the UI that must depend on the domain, not the other way round. IOW, you don't want to import "gui" in "core" but to import "core" in "gui".

If the gui needs to be notified of some events / conditions by the core, you can use some variant of [the observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

As a side note: never use star imports ("from something import *") - except possibly in a python shell or a one-shot throw-away script - if you value your mental sanity.

Comment: thank you all for your responses. As suggested I did some changes in my code and now GUI depends on the "core" modules btw I'm still dealing with this. The point is that the foo function calls other variables assigned in core modules so I can't simply move this function to gui

Comment: "The point is that the foo function calls other variables assigned in core modules" => as a general rule, your functions should not depend on global variables but on their arguments (and/or on the object's state for methods) - except for "set once change never" globals like settings etc of course -, and they should NEVER update globals, but return values (and/or update the object's state for methods).

Comment: Oh and yes: one does not "call" a variable (unless the variable is a function, method or class of course) ;-)